# I am getting info null when I using signinManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to implement the login with google functionality in asp.net core web api using identity external provider. All things are going well but when my url is redirecting to this external-auth-callback function I am getting info null. This is the external-auth-callback function.

program.cs file authentication code

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie()
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
    (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Secret"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
}).AddGoogle(opt =>
{
    opt.ClientId = builder.Configuration["GoogleLoginProvider:ClientId"];
    opt.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["GoogleLoginProvider:ClientSecret"];
    opt.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
});
```

public async Task ExternalLoginCallback([FromQuery] string returnUrl)
{

```
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info != null)
        {
            var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider,
          info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
            return new MessageViewModel()
            {
                IsSuccess = signInResult.Succeeded,
                Message = "User with this account is already in table",
            };
        }
        else
        {
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new Users
                {
                    UserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                    Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                    FirstName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName),
                    LastName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Surname),
                };
                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            }
            await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return new MessageViewModel()
            {
                IsSuccess = true,
                Message = "User with this account is created successfully"
            };
        }
    }
```

Before that i am returning the return url through this method

public async Task ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
var redirectUrl = $"https://localhost:7008/api/account/external-auth-callback?returnUrl={returnUrl}";
var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
properties.AllowRefresh = true;

```
        return new LoginProviderViewModel()
        {
            Provider = provider,
            Properties = properties,
        };
    }
```

from my frontend when i click on login with google button this method is called and after coming to this method first externalLogin method will called and I returning with return url after that in frontend i got google sign in page and when i select user then it goes to external-auth-callback function which is used to save the user who try to login with google.

const handleExternalLogin = async () => {
const url = `${externalLogin}?provider=Google&returnUrl=/admin-dashboard`;
const response = await getData(url);
if (response.isSuccessfull) {
const redirectUrl = response.data.properties.items[".redirect"];
const loginProvider = response.data.properties.items["LoginProvider"];
const googleAuthorizationUrl =
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` +
`?client_id=xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com` +
`&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}` +
`&response_type=code` +
`&scope=openid%20profile%20email` +
`&state=${loginProvider}`;
window.location.href = googleAuthorizationUrl;
}
};

Please help me out as I have stucked to this point from 2 days.

I have tried all the possible checks but not understanding why the info is showing null in external-auth-callback function? So I was expecting to please anyone let me know why I getting the null value.

Comment: Can you describe how your authentication scheme is defined? And do you use the Google JS platform library in your front-end?

Comment: No I have not use any js platform library in frontent. I have simply passing one redirect uri that is same with while creating app in google cloud

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning Challengeresult instead of ViewModel. This allows ASP.NET CORE to trigger the specified authentication scheme when executing ChallengeResult:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ExternalLogin")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{

     var redirectUrl = $https://xxx/ExternalLoginCallback?returnUrl={returnUrl};
     var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
     properties.AllowRefresh = true;
     return new ChallengeResult (provider, properties);
}
```

When I call method `_signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()`:
[image]

**Update:**

My page:

```
<form id="externalLoginForm" action="/api/Account/ExternalLogin" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="provider" value="Google">
    
    <button type="submit">Google</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("ExternalLoginCallback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
    {
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
         
            return BadRequest("Failed to get external login info");
        }

     
        if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        {
            return Ok("SIGN IN");
        }

     
        var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider,
            info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: false);

        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok("User with this account is already in table");
            
        }
        else
        {
        
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    UserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                    Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                };
                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            }

            await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

           return Ok("User with this account is created successfully");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ExternalLogin")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin([FromForm] string provider)
    {
      
        var redirectUrl = $" https://localhost:7266/api/Account/ExternalLoginCallback";
        
        
       var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        properties.AllowRefresh = true;

        return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
    }
}
```

My program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
   
    googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
   
});
```

After I click the button I'm redirected to the Google login page:
[image]

I can get the information in info successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help but this solution not working. When I return the challenge result then it throws the cors error in my console. Even I had add the cors in my program.cs file. I got the following error in my console when it returning the challenge result. Like that

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth.... (redirected from 'https://localhost:7008/api/Account/externalLogin?provider=Google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Can you describe your CORS configuration related code? Is there a configuration related Origin?

Comment: builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS",
        policy =>
        {
            policy
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

app.UseCors("EnableCORS");

Comment: Please check the program.cs authentication code that i have written above for more understanding regarding code

Comment: After my testing, you don't need to configure the relevant external login in your js. I have provided an example in the updated part of the answer that you can use as a reference.